# Spring Cloud Bus fails to recover after network outage

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-bus

I have a Spring Cloud Stream application using RabbitMQ binder, built on Spring Boot `1.5` and Spring Cloud `Edgware.SR4`. For some reason, Spring Cloud Bus fails to recover from a 
network outage that lasts at least 30 seconds (duration may depend on your environment). If the network outage is long enough for RabbitMQ to have deleted the exclusive queue, the application
is able to re-declare the anonymous queue. This seems to be a recurring event that conincides with the systems patching/restarts of the RabbitMQ server.

I duplicated the error in this [sample application](https://github.com/buwi/spring-cloud-sample), by connecting to a remote RabbitMQ server and disconnecting the network connection on my laptop. [output.txt](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/buwi/spring-cloud-sample/master/output.txt) has the entire stdout from the test.

Here's an outline of events:

### declared springCloudBus anonymous queue:

```
2018-12-17 08:37:45.633 DEBUG 13983 --- [           main] o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin         : declaring Queue 'springCloudBus.anonymous.p6jqufA8Trmx6DqbNo1uPQ'
```

### springCloudBus anonymous queue consumer init:

```
2018-12-17 08:37:45.881 DEBUG 13983 --- [pool-2-thread-7] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : ConsumeOK: Consumer@503556cb: tags=[{amq.ctag-s-IYhxP4bXEjrglFIuQr-w=springCloudBus.anonymous.p6jqufA8Trmx6DqbNo1uPQ}], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://<my.rabbit.user>@<my.rabbit.ip>:<my.rabbit.port>/notification,1), conn: Proxy@71b0289b Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@6f2d3391 [delegate=amqp://<my.rabbit.user>@<my.rabbit.ip>:<my.rabbit.port>/notification, localPort= 52315], acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
```

### network connection severed:

```
2018-12-17 08:40:23.254 DEBUG 13983 --- [rmx6DqbNo1uPQ-1] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Retrieving delivery for Consumer@503556cb: tags=[{amq.ctag-s-IYhxP4bXEjrglFIuQr-w=springCloudBus.anonymous.p6jqufA8Trmx6DqbNo1uPQ}], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://<my.rabbit.user>@<my.rabbit.ip>:<my.rabbit.port>/notification,1), conn: Proxy@71b0289b Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@6f2d3391 [delegate=amqp://<my.rabbit.user>@<my.rabbit.ip>:<my.rabbit.port>/notification, localPort= 52315], acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2018-12-17 08:40:23.687 DEBUG 13983 --- [.input.sample-1] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Retrieving delivery for Consumer@a03529c: tags=[{amq.ctag-3ZNc-38WQH4RfRA6fCmurQ=test.input.sample}], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://<my.rabbit.user>@<my.rabbit.ip>:<my.rabbit.port>/notification,2), conn: Proxy@71b0289b Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@6f2d3391 [delegate=amqp://<my.rabbit.user>@<my.rabbit.ip>:<my.rabbit.port>/notification, localPort= 52315], acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2018-12-17 08:40:23.724 ERROR 13983 --- [.<my.rabbit.ip>:<my.rabbit.port>] c.r.c.impl.ForgivingExceptionHandler     : An unexpected connection driver error occured

java.net.SocketException: Operation timed out (Read failed)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:983) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:940) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedByte(DataInputStream.java:288) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Frame.readFrom(Frame.java:91) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.readFrame(SocketFrameHandler.java:164) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:602) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_162]
```

### network connection restored:

```
2018-12-17 08:41:59.535  INFO 13983 --- [input.sample-12] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Restarting Consumer@7ca9d55c: tags=[{}], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2018-12-17 08:41:59.535 DEBUG 13983 --- [input.sample-12] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Closing Rabbit Channel: null
2018-12-17 08:41:59.535 DEBUG 13983 --- [input.sample-13] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Starting consumer Consumer@7f088f6f: tags=[{}], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2018-12-17 08:41:59.864  INFO 13983 --- [mx6DqbNo1uPQ-13] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Created new connection: rabbitConnectionFactory#3db1ce78:23/SimpleConnection@39241539 [delegate=amqp://<my.rabbit.user>@<my.rabbit.ip>:<my.rabbit.port>/notification, localPort= 52463]
2018-12-17 08:41:59.865 DEBUG 13983 --- [mx6DqbNo1uPQ-13] o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin         : Initializing declarations
2018-12-17 08:41:59.867 DEBUG 13983 --- [mx6DqbNo1uPQ-13] o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin         : Nothing to declare
2018-12-17 08:41:59.867 DEBUG 13983 --- [mx6DqbNo1uPQ-13] o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin         : Initializing declarations
2018-12-17 08:41:59.868  INFO 13983 --- [mx6DqbNo1uPQ-13] o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin         : Auto-declaring a non-durable, auto-delete, or exclusive Queue (springCloudBus.anonymous.p6jqufA8Trmx6DqbNo1uPQ) durable:false, auto-delete:true, exclusive:true. It will be redeclared if the broker stops and is restarted while the connection factory is alive, but all messages will be lost.
```

### consumer exception on trying to read from springCloudBus anonymous queue:

```
2018-12-17 08:42:17.748 DEBUG 13983 --- [mx6DqbNo1uPQ-13] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it

org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.io.IOException
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:71) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.RabbitAccessor.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitAccessor.java:113) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1469) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1419) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1395) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.initialize(RabbitAdmin.java:579) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin$11$1.doWithRetry(RabbitAdmin.java:486) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:287) ~[spring-retry-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:164) ~[spring-retry-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin$11.onCreate(RabbitAdmin.java:481) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CompositeConnectionListener.onCreate(CompositeConnectionListener.java:33) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:594) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils$1.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:90) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.doGetTransactionalResourceHolder(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:140) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.getTransactionalResourceHolder(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:76) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.start(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:576) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1504) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_162]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: null
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:124) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:120) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:142) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclare(ChannelN.java:958) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclare(ChannelN.java:53) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor157.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedChannelInvocationHandler.invoke(CachingConnectionFactory.java:1029) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy113.queueDeclare(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.declareQueues(RabbitAdmin.java:655) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.access$200(RabbitAdmin.java:72) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin$12.doInRabbit(RabbitAdmin.java:584) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1463) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=405, reply-text=RESOURCE_LOCKED - cannot obtain exclusive access to locked queue 'springCloudBus.anonymous.p6jqufA8Trmx6DqbNo1uPQ' in vhost 'notification', class-id=50, method-id=10)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:66) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:36) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:443) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:263) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:136) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=405, reply-text=RESOURCE_LOCKED - cannot obtain exclusive access to locked queue 'springCloudBus.anonymous.p6jqufA8Trmx6DqbNo1uPQ' in vhost 'notification', class-id=50, method-id=10)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.asyncShutdown(ChannelN.java:515) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.processAsync(ChannelN.java:340) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleCompleteInboundCommand(AMQChannel.java:162) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleFrame(AMQChannel.java:109) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.readFrame(AMQConnection.java:676) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.access$300(AMQConnection.java:48) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:603) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    ... 1 common frames omitted
```

### last "RESOURCE_LOCKED" exception

```
2018-12-17 08:42:43.793  WARN 13983 --- [mx6DqbNo1uPQ-15] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Queue declaration failed; retries left=2

org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer$DeclarationException: Failed to declare queue(s):[springCloudBus.anonymous.p6jqufA8Trmx6DqbNo1uPQ]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.attemptPassiveDeclarations(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:706) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.start(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:596) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1504) [spring-rabbit-1.7.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_162]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: null
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:124) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:120) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:142) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclarePassive(ChannelN.java:1002) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclarePassive(ChannelN.java:53) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedChannelInvocationHandler.invoke(CachingConnectionFactory.java:1029) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy113.queueDeclarePassive(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.attemptPassiveDeclarations(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:685) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 3 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=405, reply-text=RESOURCE_LOCKED - cannot obtain exclusive access to locked queue 'springCloudBus.anonymous.p6jqufA8Trmx6DqbNo1uPQ' in vhost 'notification', class-id=50, method-id=10)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:66) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:36) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:443) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:263) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:136) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    ... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=405, reply-text=RESOURCE_LOCKED - cannot obtain exclusive access to locked queue 'springCloudBus.anonymous.p6jqufA8Trmx6DqbNo1uPQ' in vhost 'notification', class-id=50, method-id=10)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.asyncShutdown(ChannelN.java:515) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.processAsync(ChannelN.java:340) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleCompleteInboundCommand(AMQChannel.java:162) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleFrame(AMQChannel.java:109) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.readFrame(AMQConnection.java:676) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.access$300(AMQConnection.java:48) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:603) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    ... 1 common frames omitted
```

### recurring error:

```
2018-12-17 08:42:49.781 DEBUG 13983 --- [mx6DqbNo1uPQ-15] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Detected closed channel on exception.  Re-initializing: AMQChannel(amqp://<my.rabbit.user>@<my.rabbit.ip>:<my.rabbit.port>/notification,3)
2018-12-17 08:42:49.800  WARN 13983 --- [mx6DqbNo1uPQ-15] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Failed to declare queue: springCloudBus.anonymous.p6jqufA8Trmx6DqbNo1uPQ
2018-12-17 08:42:49.801  WARN 13983 --- [mx6DqbNo1uPQ-15] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Queue declaration failed; retries left=1

org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer$DeclarationException: Failed to declare queue(s):[springCloudBus.anonymous.p6jqufA8Trmx6DqbNo1uPQ]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.attemptPassiveDeclarations(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:706) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.start(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:596) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1504) [spring-rabbit-1.7.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_162]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: null
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:124) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:120) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:142) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclarePassive(ChannelN.java:1002) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclarePassive(ChannelN.java:53) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedChannelInvocationHandler.invoke(CachingConnectionFactory.java:1029) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy113.queueDeclarePassive(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.attemptPassiveDeclarations(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:685) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 3 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no queue 'springCloudBus.anonymous.p6jqufA8Trmx6DqbNo1uPQ' in vhost 'notification', class-id=50, method-id=10)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:66) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:36) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:443) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:263) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:136) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    ... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no queue 'springCloudBus.anonymous.p6jqufA8Trmx6DqbNo1uPQ' in vhost 'notification', class-id=50, method-id=10)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.asyncShutdown(ChannelN.java:515) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.processAsync(ChannelN.java:340) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleCompleteInboundCommand(AMQChannel.java:162) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleFrame(AMQChannel.java:109) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.readFrame(AMQConnection.java:676) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.access$300(AMQConnection.java:48) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:603) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    ... 1 common frames omitted


2018-12-17 08:44:04.527 ERROR 13983 --- [mx6DqbNo1uPQ-18] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Consumer received fatal=false exception on startup

org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.QueuesNotAvailableException: Cannot prepare queue for listener. Either the queue doesn't exist or the broker will not allow us to use it.
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.start(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:628) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1504) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_162]
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer$DeclarationException: Failed to declare queue(s):[springCloudBus.anonymous.p6jqufA8Trmx6DqbNo1uPQ]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.attemptPassiveDeclarations(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:706) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.start(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:596) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 2 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: null
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:124) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:120) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:142) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclarePassive(ChannelN.java:1002) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclarePassive(ChannelN.java:53) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor161.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedChannelInvocationHandler.invoke(CachingConnectionFactory.java:1029) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy113.queueDeclarePassive(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.attemptPassiveDeclarations(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:685) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 3 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no queue 'springCloudBus.anonymous.p6jqufA8Trmx6DqbNo1uPQ' in vhost 'notification', class-id=50, method-id=10)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:66) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:36) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:443) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:263) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:136) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    ... 11 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no queue 'springCloudBus.anonymous.p6jqufA8Trmx6DqbNo1uPQ' in vhost 'notification', class-id=50, method-id=10)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.asyncShutdown(ChannelN.java:515) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.processAsync(ChannelN.java:340) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleCompleteInboundCommand(AMQChannel.java:162) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleFrame(AMQChannel.java:109) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.readFrame(AMQConnection.java:676) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.access$300(AMQConnection.java:48) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:603) ~[amqp-client-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    ... 1 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 3):

It means there is some excessive delay in the broker seeing the original consumer die; since the queue is exclusive, this prevents the recovery from re-declaring the queue when the connection is re-established.

The `RabbitAdmin` has the following retry configuration (when none is explicitly defined):

```
            this.retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
            this.retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(new SimpleRetryPolicy(5));
            ExponentialBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new ExponentialBackOffPolicy();
            backOffPolicy.setInitialInterval(1000);
            backOffPolicy.setMultiplier(2.0);
            backOffPolicy.setMaxInterval(5000);
            this.retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy);
```

So it will try 5 times and give up after 1 + 2 + 4 + 5 (12) seconds.

Spring Cloud Stream currently doesn't support configuring its admin retry configuration. I suggest you open an issue against the [rabbit binder](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/issues).

Comment: Gary, thank you for the explanation.

I have opened an issue on GitHub. (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/issues/191)

Comment: So for now there is no apparent solution for this problem?

Comment: There's an open issue [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/issues/191) looks like it was never addressed; I suggest you ping it.